# Text field keeping track of count in QT using QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicstextitem

I have a QT-project (using C++) where instances of a certain user-defined `QGraphicsItem` called `Person` move around the scene. Sometimes those `Persons` interact so that some of them change color.

Now I want to put a text field in the window and display counts of how many I have of each color. But since the change occurs within the call to the `Person::advance`-method I want to create a text field that can be updated from within these.

I could easily display some text by adding the following code to my main.cpp:

```
    QGraphicsSimpleTextItem *text1 = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
    text1->setPos(-200, -150);
    text1->setText("This is an arbitrary English sentence");
    scene.addItem(text1);
```

but I do not know how to access and alter the text of this variable `text1` from within the `advance`-method of the `Persons` in my scene. What is a good strategy for this?

> Should I create a global variable keeping track of the count, and if I do, how can I then update the text field? Or should the text not even be on my `QGraphicsScene`, but rather be defined in some other more appropriate place where it is callable from everywhere in the program? Is there a generic way of doing this?

Comment: Seems to be a good job for qt's signal-slot system

Comment: @thuga: OK, no problem.

Comment: @simon: Thank you! I will try to read more about it. Although my program already uses a `QTimer`, I am not that familiar with qt's signal-slot system yet, since the `QTimer`-statements was simply taken from another example, so I do not yet understand exactly how it works/how the syntax and structure is.

Comment: @thuga: OK, but does that mean that I have to pass that pointer to every single `Person`? Right now I only have a `Person`-class and not a mother class called `Persons`, so for all instances of `Person` to know the reference, I would have to pass it on each initialization of a `Person`, correct?

Comment: If you use Qt, you will definitely need signals/slots, it's better to get familiar with them as soon as possible.

Comment: It seems my initial comment was correct. You could subclass `QGraphicsObject` instead of `QGraphicsItem`, that would allow you to use signals from within the `Person` class. Then just emit a signal to a slot that counts the items and changes the text of `text1`.

Comment: @simon: No doubt about that! I am new to Qt, but I will get there, eventually. The sooner the better!

Comment: @thuga: From reading the first line of the documentation of the `QGraphicsObject` class, it seems that you are absolutely correct! Would it make sense to make a mother class called `Persons` (subclass to `QGraphicsObject`) just to give it the single goal to store the reference to the text fields that display counts and then subclass it by `Person`?

Comment: @thuga: I urge both of you to turn your comments into answers. You provided exactly the information, I was looking for.

Comment: @simon: I urge both of you to turn your comments into answers. You provided exactly the information, I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsobject.html) instead of `QGraphicsItem`, that would allow you to use signals from within the Person class. Then just emit a signal to a slot that counts the items and changes the text of text1.

What I would do is move your graphics view to a new `QWidget` type class (like [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html)). This is to make it easier to handle signals and slots, and it will also allow you to use member variables. It will also be cleaner than doing everything in `main.cpp`.

You could have your `text1` variable as a member variable of this `MainWindow` class. This would make accessing it easy.

Your slot in the `MainWindow` class could look something like this:

```
MainWindow::countItems()
{
    int redcount = 0;
    int greencount = 0;
    int bluecount = 0;
    // iterate through your `Person` items and check their colors and count them
    text1->setText(QString("Red items: %1, Green items: %2, Blue items: %3").arg(redcount).arg(greencount).arg(bluecount));
}
```

You can improve the logic, but this is just a basic example.

Comment: Thank you very much! There is a lot to learn when you are new to Qt, but this took me a step forward.